# Angular: Get path param in App-routing.module context

Tags: angular

I have an Angular resolver for one of my routes that I want to pass the ':category' path variable into my resolver data.category property like this:

```js
{
    path: 'mywines/:category/:type/:index',
    component: WinesViewerComponent,
    resolve: {
        apiData: ApiResolver
    },
    data: {
        resolveMethod: 'getMyWinesData',
        category: <get the value of ':category' pass it here>
    },
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
}
```

The path value for this scenario is: `"/#/mywines/cellar/gallery/0"`.

Is there a way to get that path param when I'm in the context of the app-routing.module?

Comment: I don't think you can get the value there, but you should be able to obtain it within the resolver itself since it is passed the `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` (see https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve)

Comment: Maybe it's simpler just to have a different path for each category instead (there's only 3).